# Retry inner Observable,

Tags: rxjs

I have an outer and inner `Observable`. The inner Obersvable has sometimes errors, which can be worked around with retries.

```js
function sm$(val) {
  if (Math.random() > .4) {
    return Rx.Observable.throw(val)
  } else {
    return Rx.Observable.of(val)
  }
}

function sm(val) {
  return Rx.Observable.of(val)
    .switchMap(sm$)
    .catch(() => Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(1000).switchMap(sm))
}

Rx.Observable
  .interval(500)
  .switchMap(sm)
  .take(5)
  .subscribe(
    val => console.log("val:", val),
    err => console.log("err:", err),
    () => console.log("complete")
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

this log i.e.:

```
val: 1
val: 2
val: 6
val: 10
val: 11
complete
```

When I return a delayed observable in the catch block, it is not working properly some values are just skipped. Without the delay it works as expected, but that's not what I want. I want the repeated exectution to be delayed.

```js
function sm$(val) {
  if (Math.random() > .4) {
    return Rx.Observable.throw(val)
  } else {
    return Rx.Observable.of(val)
  }
}

function sm(val) {
  return Rx.Observable.of(val)
    .switchMap(sm$)
    .catch(() => Rx.Observable.of(val).switchMap(sm))
    // removed the delay(1000)
}

Rx.Observable
  .interval(500)
  .switchMap(sm)
  .take(5)
  .subscribe(
    val => console.log("val:", val),
    err => console.log("err:", err),
    () => console.log("complete")
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

this log always looks like this, and this is what I expect:

```
val: 0
val: 1
val: 2
val: 3
val: 4
complete
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `Observable.interval(500).switchMap(sm)`.

In particular the `switchMap` in your case. The source `Observable.interval` keeps emitting even when you use `delay(1000)` on the inner Observable just because of `switchMap` it already unsubscribed when it wants to emit after 1000ms.

So it looks like you could to use `concatMap` instead of the outer `switchMap`.

```js
function sm$(val) {
  if (Math.random() > .4) {
    return Rx.Observable.throw(val)
  } else {
    return Rx.Observable.of(val)
  }
}

function sm(val) {
  return Rx.Observable.of(val)
    .switchMap(sm$)
    .catch(() => Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(1000).switchMap(sm))
}

Rx.Observable
  .interval(500)
  .concatMap(sm)
  .take(5)
  .subscribe(
    val => console.log("val:", val),
    err => console.log("err:", err),
    () => console.log("complete")
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.4.0/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the fact that you use a delay of 1000 ms while at the same time you complete the stream after the emission of 5 events, each occurring every 500 ms.

This means that a delayed emission, delayed because of the `catch` block, can arrive after the stream has been completed.

If you reduce the delay you may get what you are looking for. I have also added some logging to have a better picture

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

function sm$(val) {
    if (Math.random() > .4) {
      return Observable.throw(val)
    } else {
      return Observable.of(val)
    }
}

function sm(val) {
    return Observable.of(val)
      .switchMap(sm$)
      .catch(() => {
                        console.log('error', val);
                        return Observable.of(val).delay(10).switchMap(d => sm(d));
                    })
}

Observable
    .interval(500)
    .switchMap(sm)
    .take(5)
    .subscribe(
      val => console.log("val:", val),
      err => console.log("err:", err),
      () => console.log("complete")
    )
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I want, even I want the code to keep the order independent from any delay or intervals, I want it to work with any delay I deem necessary. This code is an example, actually I don't know the timings.